Solr - C# query appending "s" to sort field
Our sort order is not working correctly, and I found it's because the solr query being generated ends with sort=date_tdts%20desc - when it should end with sort=date_tdt%20desc (note the extra 's'). But I'm not sure where this extra s is coming from in the code. This is the index field configuration:
[IndexField("date_tdt")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }

Here is the code that generates the query:
    var orderExpression = searchAdapter.MapFilterToOrder(query, out bool orderByDescending);

    var resultsQueryable = providerSearchContext.GetQueryable<TSearchItem>()
        .Where(basePredicate);

    if(query.Filters != null)
    {
        var queryPredicate = CombinePredicates(query.Filters.Select(searchAdapter.MapFilterToPredicate));
        resultsQueryable = resultsQueryable.Where(queryPredicate);
    }

    if (orderExpression != null)
    {
        resultsQueryable = orderByDescending
            ? resultsQueryable.OrderByDescending(orderExpression)
            : resultsQueryable.OrderBy(orderExpression);
    }


    public virtual Expression<Func<ArticleSearchResultItem, object>> MapFilterToOrder(SearchQuery query,
        out bool @descending)
    {
        @descending = true;

        return x => x.Date;
    }

why is it appending an s to date_tdt?

The <fieldMap> in the solution (not in Solr) needed to be updated so that it knew what type to treat the field as:
  <contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
          <defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
              <fieldMap>
                  <fieldNames>
                      <field fieldName="date_tdt" returnType="datetime"></field>
                  </fieldNames>
              </fieldMap>
          </defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
  </contentSearch>

